# how to assign name to every item on list python i dont want to use dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops

i have two list

> A = [x1,x2,x3,....x54]

and

> B= [[abc,bcd,cde],[123,234,345],[a1,b1,c1].....] (B also has 54
> elements)

now i want to assign and get output as

```
x1=[abc,bcd,cde]
x2=[123,234,345]
x3=[a1,b1,c1].....
x54=[...]
```

can someone please help
I have tired

`x1= B[0]`

but I want to iterate 54 times.

Comment: To clarify you just want a way to map one value to another across two lists?

Comment: Just want to know your use case for having to do this?

Comment: Dictionaries...

Comment: Why don't you just use a dictionary?

Comment: use case is too big . i jst edited the question . how i want my output

Comment: i dont want to use dictionary because these are column names.